# XPath functions: substring, substring-after with XPathNavigator.Select

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

Is it possible to select substrings of selected node values with XPathNavigator.Select ?

For example, what I am trying to do is:

```
xPath = @"//object/@data/substring-after(., '\')"

var pathNavigator = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
var pathNodeIterator = pathNavigator.Select(xPath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET realization -- not. You should use .NET string functions after obtaining desired result.